# Updating a <div> in a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, file-io

I am trying to html and javascript code to print out a text file line by line. Code I have is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function loadXMLDoc()
    {
        var xhr, i, text, lines;

        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            // IE5, IE6  - next line supports these dinosaurs
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
            {
                text = xhr.responseText;
                lines = text.split("\n"); 

                for(i = 1; i < lines.length; i++)
                { 
                    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML + "\n" + lines[i];
                }
            }
        }

        xhr.open("GET","File.txt",true);
        xhr.send();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2></h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
```

I figured this line:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML + "\n" + lines[i];
```

Would take whats currently in the , post a new line, and post the new line from the text file. The problem is when I run it in the browser its not (or I dont think it is) posting the new line its just posting it horizontally with a space.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: The document you are working is Content-type of `text/html` so you need `<br>` tag.

Comment: I strongly suggest using jQuery to simplify the work of sending HTTP request and DOM modification >:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New lines in HTML are denoted as line break (`<br>`). Change your \n to that and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 1 of this

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
    {
        text = xhr.responseText;
        lines = text.split("\n"); 

        for(i = 1; i < lines.length; i++)
        { 
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML + "<br>" + lines[i];
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
    {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML + xhr.responseText.replace(/[\r\n]/g, "<br>");

    }
}
```

Comment: Second sample is probably more performant than enumerating all rows. Although suspect you will get 2 line breaks if using Windows style line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

up to HTML 4 br

HTML 5 
 or br/ is ok

In XHTML br /